# SQL Joining Issue with 2 fields in one table

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a report from two tables, the first table `NNVehicleQuote` contains vehicle information and two of the columns refer to parking, one for day parking, `NNVehicleQuote.dayparking`, and one for night parking, `NNVehicleQuote.nightparking`. In this table each of these columns show the `Id` and not the description.

I am trying to run a query that will show both column's actual descriptions from the lookup table `LU_PARKING`. If I run them individually the query runs fine but when I try to run both, I get an error.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM NNVehicleQuote
INNER JOIN LU_PARKING AS dayparking ON LU_PARKING.id = NNVehicleQuote.dayparking
INNER JOIN LU_PARKING AS nightparking ON LU_PARKING.id = NNVehicleQuote.nightparking
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Perhaps LEFT JOIN? (For example if a LU_PARKING has no night parking.)

Comment: Hi, the error is Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "LU_PARKING.id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "LU_PARKING.id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the alias rather than the table name in the join:

```
select *
from NNVehicleQuote
INNER JOIN LU_PARKING AS dayparking ON dayparking.id = NNVehicleQuote.dayparking
INNER JOIN LU_PARKING AS nightparking ON nightparking.id = NNVehicleQuote.nightparking
```

Comment: Thank You Richard, this solution worked. Many Thanks